# Load Products by SKU Using Dependency Injection

Tags: magento2.4.1, widget

I am building a custom widget that I want to display specific products based on the product SKU. I have tried a few different code examples to get products using the dependency injection method, but when I try to get the product name, it errs.

```
Error: Call to a member function getName() on null
```

The products I am trying to get are all enabled and exist in the database, so I don't see any reason for it to not be able to get the name.

Not sure what exactly I'm missing ...

These are the tutorials I have looked at:

https://www.magetrend.com/blog/magento-2-get-product-by-sku-or-id/

https://magecomp.com/blog/load-products-by-id-and-sku-in-magento-2/

https://www.hiddentechies.com/blog/magento-2/magento-2-get-product-by-sku/

/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
<widget class="Vendor\Module\Block\Widget\Featuredproducts" id="vendor_module_featuredproducts">
    <label>Featured Products</label>
    <description>Enter SKUs for products to feature</description>
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="featuredproductsid" sort_order="10" visible="true" xsi:type="text">
            <label>SKUs (comma separated)</label>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
</widget>
</widgets>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Widget/Featuredproducts.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Widget;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;

class Featuredproducts extends Template implements BlockInterface
{
    protected $_template = "widget/featuredproducts.phtml";
}
```

/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Widgets.php

```
<?php
  namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

 class Widgets extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {  
  public $_productRepository;
    
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,       
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductById($id)
{
    return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
}

public function getProductBySku($sku)
{
    return $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
}
}
?>
```

/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/widget/featuredproducts.phtml

```
<?php if($block->getData('featuredproductsid')): 

  $featuredSkus = $block->getData('featuredproductsid'); 
  $arr_featuredSkus = explode(',', $featuredSkus);?>

 <div class="featured-products-rotator">
   <?php foreach($arr_featuredSkus as $sku) { 

    $prod = $block->getProductDataUsingSku($sku); ?>

    <a href="#" class="product-content">
      <span class="headline"><?php echo $prod->getName(); ?></span>
    </a>

  <?php } ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

--

When I use the ObjectManager method, each of the items list as expected.

```
$product = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::class)
        ->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
```

I want to use the dependency injection method, as that is the recommended way to do it. Totally stumped ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After making the change that @simonthesorcerer suggested, I ended up deleting my widgets.php file and adding the content that was in it to the Featuredproducts.php file.

The featuredproducts.php now looks like this:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Widget;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;

class Featuredproducts extends Template implements BlockInterface
{
protected $_template = "widget/featuredproducts.phtml";

protected $_productRepository;
    
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,      
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductById($id)
{
    return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
}

public function getProductBySku($sku)
{
    return $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

method `getProductDataUsingSku` is undefined, which means it falls back on the magic `__get()` method. Replace it in your template with `getProductBySku`

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. Ran all the setup:upgrade and cache clearing stuff.